# Stripe Subscriptions - Create even if first billing attempt fails

Tags: stripe-payments, subscriptions

On Stripe's API docs the value returned when attempting to create a subscription on a customer is described as follows:

> The newly created subscription object if the call succeeded. If the customer has no card or the attempted charge fails, this call returns an error (unless the specified plan is free or has a trial period).

From this, I am assuming that if the first attempted charge fails (and an error is returned) this means that the subscription has not been created?

I am wanting to be able to create subscriptions on customers who may not yet have any billing sources added and as soon as they add a billing source the first payment will be processed. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From this, I am assuming that if the first attempted charge fails (and an error is returned) this means that the subscription has not been created?

Yes, that's correct.

> I am wanting to be able to create subscriptions on customers who may not yet have any billing sources added and as soon as they add a billing source the first payment will be processed. Is there a way to accomplish this?

You could create a subscription with a plan for $0, or create a sub with a trial using `trial_end` to create a 'free' subscription.

As far as "as soon as they add a billing source the first payment will be processed." -- you'd need to create logic to handle this on your own. When a user adds a payment source you could update their subscription ending the trial (`trial_end=now`), or moving them to a paid plan.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of an approach similar to this one. The issue is that it negates a lot of the convenience of using subscriptions in the first place. When it comes time for a subscription to be renewed, if billing fails for some reason Stripe will automatically retry in a few days (or whatever schedule is specified) - and will immediately retry if billing information is updated. Why can't it do this when the subscription is first created? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @abagshaw if you want to use the retry logic: one solution might be to create a sub with a 5 minute trial (using `trial_end`). It will start regardless of whether the customer has a valid credit card. When the super short trial expires it will try to bill, fail, retry per your instructions.

Comment: That is almost what I am looking for, but unfortunately my understanding is that if a customer adds a card say 5 days later and then the first invoice is successfully charged, the next invoice date won't be shifted forward 5 days, it will remain a month (or whatever interval I set) in advance of when the invoice was first created. So I'll have to manually bump the next invoice date forward which defeats the purpose. I've marked your answer as accepted as it's as close as I think I'm going to get.